# Prove that regular languages are closed under Kleene star

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

Given $L$ is a regular language, how can I prove that $L^*$ is a regular language too?
I've constructed an NFA which contains a new initial state that has an $\epsilon$-transition to the original initial state, and also connected all the final states to the original initial state with an $\epsilon$-transition.

How can I formally prove that this is correct?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/83602/755

Comment: The formal proof depends on the exact definitions used in your class.